# Railway "stream did not contain valid UTF-8" issue

Tags: hosting

I keep getting this error when deploying one of my websites with railway.app

```
Nixpacks build failed
 
Error: stream did not contain valid UTF-8
```

This error doesn't tell me much. I've researched all I can and still stick. Using the Railway CLI tool I ran `railway logs` and still get no information.

Would anybody be able to point me in the right direction to get a more descriptive log?

Comment: I saw an alert of GitHub when I opened up to edit my requirements.txt file that read: 

```We’ve detected the file encoding as UTF-16LE. When you commit changes we will transcode it to UTF-8.
```
Once I re-committed my deployment worked and the error went away. The way I understand it is that one of the first things railway does on deployment is install all the requirements in this file. Therefore the encoding of this file would not allow railway to do so. I still have little knowledge on the issue but am slowly making progress and will keep updating here.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. I had to change the file encoding of *requirements.txt* from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 and it worked